# Wordpress shortcode not rendering in Yoast og:title

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, yoast

I have a simple shortcode which i use on post titles:

```
add_shortcode('year', 'year_shortcode');
function year_shortcode() {
    $year = date('Y');
    return $year;
}

add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'my_shortcode_title' );
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_shortcode_title' );
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'my_shortcode_title');
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'my_shortcode_title' );

function my_shortcode_title( $title ){
    return do_shortcode( $title );
}
```

It works fine but I suddenly realized that Yoast creates an `og:title` and it doesn't render there (meaning it doesn't render on Facebook or whatsapp)

I searched for an answer and couldn't find anythinng.
Has anyone faced this before?

Maybe I need to run the og:title through a filter of some sort which is also fine, the question is how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you asked Yoast support about this. That should be your first stop.

Comment: good ides, just sent a question on the support page. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this and it mostly works.
It will update the og:title, and socials etc in Yoast.

It does not update Yoast's default Schema output. This would probably need to be addressed by them.

```
// Create Year shortcode to replace with current year.
add_shortcode( 'currentyear', 'current_year' );
function current_year() {
    $year = date( 'Y' );
    return $year;
}
// Activate shortcode function in Post Title.
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'single_post_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_desc', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_site_name', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_twitter_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_twitter_description', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 'wpseo_schema_webpage' filter to To replace the [year] shortcode in the "name" field in the Schema output specifically for web pages. This filter is more targeted compared to the wpseo_json_ld_output filter, which affects the entire Schema output.

```
function replace_year_in_yoast_schema( $data ) {
$current_year = date('Y');

if ( isset( $data['@graph'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $data['@graph'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ( isset( $value['name'] ) && strpos( $value['name'], '[year]' ) !== false ) {
            $data['@graph'][$key]['name'] = str_replace('[year]', $current_year, $value['name']);
        }
    }
}

return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', 'replace_year_in_yoast_schema', 10, 1 );
```